# Fixed length structure re-arrange: should I use array or linked list?

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures

This structure will only contain exactly 256 unsigned chars. 
The only operation possible is taking random characters from it and putting them in front of the structure.
For example:

```
A= 'abcdef'
```

Move character 2 to front

```
A= 'cabdef'
```

I first thought of using linked link so that it could work as a queue.
Thing is I heard that arrays are much faster than linked lists for these operations. Is this true?

Comment: do you actually want to sort or re-arrange chars?

Comment: You're right, it's re-arrange I'll edit that

Comment: What's the size of your char list?  The answer is different if it's 6 than if it's potentially very large.

Comment: @Erandros: Than it probably doesn't matter. [Everything is fast for small N](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/everything-is-fast-for-small-n.html)

Comment: It's "thEn", with an "e". Sorry for pointing that out but the other comment confused me too :).

Comment: As a simple rule of thumb, I use `list` when I care about iterators remaining valid, not when I care about moving things around inside the structure.  In this case, if I had an iterator pointing to `a` before the rotation, with a `vector` that iterator now points to `c`, while with `list` it still points to `a`.  If that matters, stick to `list`; if it doesn't use `vector` [or `deque`].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linked list will be O(1) and an array will be O(n) for a move operation as you have described. For small `n` the array will probably be faster, but the only way to know for sure is to benchmark.

In a case like this I would code what's clearest and only worry about efficiency if it proves to be a bottleneck.

P.S. I made an assumption that you already had a pointer to the character you want to move. If this is not the case, then finding the character will be O(n) in the linked list and you will lose any advantages it might have.

Comment: I have to traverse the list to find the character.

Comment: Also keep in mind CPU caches -- the linked list is roughly 1600% overhead in comparison to the array.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you can use a `vector` instead of array or linked list. The complexity of a Linked List is O(1) like @Mark Ransom said. With the vector, you can use the command [rotate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s39wbf1w%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to perform the action you desire. The complexity is determined by the number of swaps.

From MSDN, how to use rotate:

```
   const int VECTOR_SIZE = 8;

   // Define a template class vector of strings
   typedef vector<string> StrVector;

   //Define an iterator for template class vector of strings
   typedef StrVector::iterator StrVectorIt;

   StrVector Tongue_Twister(VECTOR_SIZE);

   StrVectorIt start, end, middle, it;

   // location of first element of Tongue_Twister
   start = Tongue_Twister.begin();   

   // one past the location last element of Tongue_Twister
   end = Tongue_Twister.end();       


   // Initialize vector Tongue_Twister
   Tongue_Twister[0] = "she";
   Tongue_Twister[1] = "sells";
   Tongue_Twister[2] = "sea";
   Tongue_Twister[3] = "shells";
   Tongue_Twister[4] = "by";
   Tongue_Twister[5] = "the";
   Tongue_Twister[6] = "sea";
   Tongue_Twister[7] = "shore";

   middle = start + 3;  // start position for rotating elements

   cout << "Before calling rotate" << endl;

   // print content of Tongue_Twister
   cout << "Try this Tongue Twister:";
   for (it = start; it != end; it++)
      cout << " " << *it;

   // rotate the items in the vector Tongue_Twister by 3 positions
   rotate(start, middle, end);
```

Or you can do it with arrays:

```
// create an array of 9 elements and rotate the entire array.
int myArray[SIZE] = { 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,  };
std::rotate(myArray, myArray + 3, myArray + SIZE);
```

How fast is this? I don't know. I haven't benchmarked it. But it is much easier than having to manually swap elements of an array.

Comment: Hey, how does `std::rotate` work on a raw C array `char[]`? Will it effectively do `memmove`? Maybe that'd be the best of both worlds. Simple data structure, random access and elegant interface.

Answer (score 1):

A linked list would be a good approach since you don't need to move all the intermediate elements around. `std::list` works just fine, combined with `splice()`. You will need an iterator to the element you want to move to the front:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include "prettyprint.hpp"

int main()
{
  std::list<int> x { 1, 4, 6, 7, 2 };
  auto i = x.begin(); std::advance(i, 2);  // i points to 6

  std::cout << x << std::endl;  //  [1, 4, 6, 7, 2]

  x.splice(x.begin(), x, i);

  std::cout << x << std::endl;  //  [6, 1, 4, 7, 2]
}
```

(Using the [pretty printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers) for a quick demo.)

As others have said, whether that's more efficient that a random-access container depends on how you are tracking the element that you want to move.

---

**Update:** In light of Steve's remarks I should like to offer a raw C-array solution, too. It has the benefit that you can access it by position in O(1) time and that it requires minimum space:

```
char y[] = { 'a', 'c', 'Q', '%', '5' };
std::cout << pretty_print_array(y) << std::endl; // [a, c, Q, %, 5]
std::rotate(y, y + 2, y + sizeof(y));
std::cout << pretty_print_array(y) << std::endl; // [Q, %, 5, a, c]
```

The `rotate` call could be wrapped in a function:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void bring_forward(T (& a)[N], size_t p) { std::rotate(a, a + p, a + N); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array.  The linked list will be huge and unwieldy for storage of char data.

Comment: See below: How will this combine with `std::rotate`? Will it be as good as a hand-written routine using `memmove`?

Comment: @Kerrek - don't know for sure but often STL algorithms can be used treating pointers as iterator input parameters.  I know this works for `std::copy` for example.  I odn't see why `std::rotate` would not work the same, after a brief clance at the MSDN docs.

Comment: @Kerrek: It will probably be better than a hand written routine using memmove.

Answer (score 0):

The array will be O(1) to find the item and O(n) to move it and the other items into the correct position. The linked list will be O(n) to find the item and O(1) to move everything to the right position. The complexity is the same either way.

They're both easy to implement, so implement both of them and run tests to see which one lets your program run faster with real-world data.

Answer (score -2):

C++ arrays are linked lists, so moving an element to the front of your list is cheap, provided you already know where the element is (i.e. you have an iterator on it). Using a vector would cause the entire list to be shifted each time an element is pushed in front of it.

Comment: I think you're confused about the definition of the word "array".

Comment: Linked lists can be created by using arrays, not the inverse.